# Retrieve value from a Regex code without for loop?

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a effective way to retrieve the specific value of the myString with support of regex and without using a for loop?

```
    string myString = "BOX 646,  ff503 15";

    Regex regexp = new Regex(@"BOX [0-9]+");

    if (regexp.Match(myString).Success)
    {

    }
```

The data also can be

```
ddfdfdfN 1BOX 116
CAREER SERVICES - BOX 7080
POSTADRESS: BOX 9193
"BOX 15038, 250 15 ffff"
DT-111 87 (BOX 1703)
```

Comment: I don't see a for loop.

Comment: What is that code you've provided?  Isn't it "effective"?  If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would like to retrieve the value that is for instance "BOX 646", not about validation.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show some example input, code and output.

Comment: The whole point of having **Regular Expression** in programming is to _retrieve the specific value ( pattern ) from string_. Don't know what you are talking about loop.

Comment: @noob -- where did you get that definition?

Comment: `var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"BOX [0-9]+");
    var result = string.Empty;
    if (match.Success)
    {
        result = match.Value;
    }`

Comment: @roryap: I didn't quoted it as definition from official source. It's just a rough summation.